# Multiple Naive Bayes classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, theory, naivebayes

I'm looking at implement a Naive Byes classifier for a review site in order to identify spam reviews and have a couple of questions.

1. It occurs to me there are multiple types of spam, such as outright marketing rubbish with nothing to do with the thing they are reviewing, versus a deceptive review. Would it be wise to implement multiple classifiers for different purposes so that one gets better an general spam detection, whilst the other learns deceptive reviews?
2. On a similar vain, there are multiple categories of items being reviewed so for the "deceptive review" classifier, would it be best to have just one classifier that tries to learn from all reviews? or would it be better to have a classifier per category so that it may be able to learn nuances within those categories?

I know these won't be fool proof, it's just about flagging potential reviews for manual checking, but I'm just unclear on the best setup.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're using any sufficiently complex algorithm, you should be able to discriminate "good" vs "bad" data with either method.  If you do it all with one model, you'll simply need to increase the model size so that the comprehensive model can build (at worst) independent paths to the two decisions, "spam" and "deception".

If you're training this on three separate classifications: good, spam, and deceptive; then you're doing fine either way.  Note, however, that your model size is smaller with separate trainings, and your training times will be shorter, as there will be fewer inaccurate guesses on the way.

On the other hand, using two models for later actual use will likely slow down detection, since each output that passes the first model must be run through the second.  For most applications, this time is not a significant factor.

Most of all, I would start with a separate model for each class: any problems with implementation and training will be faster to find and easier to isolate.